# Save unicode character with linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I try to save some uincode character to Sql via linq in flow code:

```c#
 DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
 Album a = new Album();
 a.ID = "ALB00100";
 a.ArtistID = "ART00007";
 a.Title = "英语翻唱";
 db.Albums.InsertOnSubmit(a);
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

but in SQL column Title is "?????"
I use type nvarchar(150) for this column

Comment: does your code run? what kind of issue are you experiencing? I would say nvarchar data type is what you need in SQL, in .NET all strings are unicode by design, then something might depend on the collation of your database

Comment: Check the charset used for your database. You can do this by performing the following query: `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')`. If it's non-unicode, than maybe that's your problem.

Comment: @Aschratt the collation is a bit of a side issue here... the underlying column to be `nvarchar`, but *that's it* - you don't need any special collation to store unicode

Comment: Are you *sure* the column is `nvarchar` ? And more specifically, was it `nvarchar` when you generated the LINQ-to-SQL model from the database?

Comment: as @Marc Gravell said , you may need to delete and re-add your table in LINQ-to-SQL model :)

Comment: @zey or... just edit the .dbml file to tell it that it is `nvarchar`...

Comment: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS how to use than more one language on one column (ex: chinese and korean)

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell. it's well done when i edit the .dbml file

Comment: @facebook-100002976932161 Welcome to StackOverflow. Glad we could help. And now that you have an accepted answer, you should post it as an Answer here so future users won't have to read through all the comments to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your .dbml file as it was likely initially generated with the column being varchar instead of nvarchar.

Comment: Or whatever you are using the display the column isn't using a font that can display chinese characters.